# 'ViewController.Type' does not have a member named 'array'

Tags: arrays, class, swift, var

I see people are having this problem a lot.

```
var array = [1,1]

class arrays {
var array2 = array //'ViewController.Type' does not have a member named 'array'
}
```

please help

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, Please provide some more details, so people here can help. Help us to Help YOU!

Comment: Are you defining an array outside the class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are declaring a Nested class and use a `array` declared in `ViewController` into a `class arrays`. (I tried reproducing your error by adding your snippet into a ViewController, and luckily got the same error as you mentioned :-) )

Yes it is possible. see the following code.

```
var array = [1, 1]

class arrays {
    var array2 = ViewController().array
}
```

**EDIT:** It is because, In Swift, an instance of an inner class is independent of any instance of the outer class. So you need to create an explicit reference to access the property of outer class.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you explain why please?